# How to acces environment variables in a shell script executed through cron

Tags: ubuntu, cron

How can I access environment variables in a shell script executed through `cron` (on Ubuntu)?

I have the following situation

```
#crontab
* * * * * root /etc/myscript.sh
```

and

```
#myscript.sh
echo "----"
echo $DATABASE_NAME
echo "----"
```

When the cron runs, it prints

```
----

----
```

However, when I run the script manually `/etc/myscript.sh`, it prints

```
----
mydb
----
```

I have tried to add `SHELL=/bin/bash` at the top of my crontab but it did not work.

Thanks.

Comment: I am really new to Ubuntu, but i came acros something similar, and if i'm not mistaken, not all variables ar the same for all users. Try to echo `whoami` and see the user calling the script

Comment: In both cases the user is `root`,

Comment: Out of ideas..:D gl!:D

Comment: How did you set the environment variable, via `export DATABASE_NAME=mydb` in a shell? Variables set in this way are not only specific to your user, they are also specific to your bash process. Starting a new terminal, will have an unset `$DATABASE_NAME`.